# Clicking on Widget isn't opening up new Activity

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm really new to making Android apps; just trying to make a simple widget that tells the time. The widget will also open up a basic activity if you click on it. The Widget and Activity are in 2 different project files (in the same workspace), so I had to import the Activity package in to access its class.

Entire code:

```
public class FirstWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
RemoteViews view = null;


public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    view = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_textview, pendingIntent);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context, FirstWidget.class), view);


    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTime(context, appWidgetManager), 1, 1000);
}
private class MyTime extends TimerTask {
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
    ComponentName thisWidget;
    DateFormat format = SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance(SimpleDateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.getDefault());

    public MyTime(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager) {
        this.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
        thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, FirstWidget.class);
    }
    public void run() {
        Calendar cal = format.getCalendar();
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        switch (day) {
        case(2):
            view.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview, "MONDAY TIP " + format.format(new Date()));
            break;
        case(3):
            view.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview, "TUESDAY TIP " + format.format(new Date()));
            break;
        case(4):
            view.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview, "WEDNESDAY TIP " + format.format(new Date()));
            break;
        case(5):
            view.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview, "THURSDAY TIP " + format.format(new Date()));
            break;
        case(6):
            view.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview, "FRIDAY TIP " + format.format(new Date()));
            break;
        case(7):
            view.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview, "SATURDAY TIP " + format.format(new Date()));
            break;
        case(1):
            view.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview, "SUNDAY TIP " + format.format(new Date()));
            break;
        }
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, view);
    }
}
}
```

I made the Activity a Library in Eclipse, and sync'd it up to the Widget via Properties->Android->Library. Also added the Activity to the Widget's Java Build path via Properties->JAva Build Path->Activity Package.

When I import the Widget to the emultaor, both the Widget and the App get downloaded. I can also bring both to the front screen. The App works as intended (click the button, go to screen). The Widget updates its time and day every second.

But clicking on the widget does nothing.

Been looking at different tutorials for 5 hours now. Not seeing what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be great

Comment: Does your Activity open if you add it directly to your project(without library)?

Comment: Nope. I try that and the widget breaks when it tries to find my .class activity (even though it's imported and Eclipse is okay with it)

Comment: Do you get any error or warning in Logcat?Both Activity is in library or in your package?

Comment: Not when setup like this

Comment: And no error if your Activity be library?

Comment: There is an error when the Activity isn't a library. I get ClassDefNotFoundException. No error when it IS a library

Comment: Getting a warning that there is "No content provider found for permission revoke: file///data/local/tmp/<The App>.apk

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no construction error in your `AppWigetProvider`.And you say you get `ClassDefNotFoundException` if your Activity be not library.So I guess problem is in about your "intent".It may be caused if your Activity not declared in manifest,incorrect name of Activity class on creating intent,or it may be in another package that your AppWidgetProvider is defined in it.So I propose create a test Activity(in package of your AppWidgetProvider) and set it as "Launcher" then try to open your "MainActivity" from it.If any intent be successful in opening "MainActivity",it may be suitable intent to be used in "AppWidgetProvider" to create your "pendingintent".

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out, there were 2 major issues.

1) My Widget's Manifest needed to state ALL the activites for the App, not just the main page (My App had 2 pages)

```
<activity android:name="com.example.aubreysapp.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.aubreysapp.DisplayMessageActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

2) With that fixed, I got yelled at that the App couldn't be installed. Unchecked it being a Library, and everything works great now.